# Vlookup with multiple conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have checked previous posts on how to vlookup using multiple conditions, however when I apply it to my workbook I get a *"#N/A"*.  I would be grateful on any feedback on what I'm doing wrong.

Issue (simple example):

`A1` = `Vlookup(B1&C1,D:E,2,False)`

- `B1` = 123
- `C1` = 45
- `D1` = 12345
- `E1` = "Good"

I expect formula to return a value of "Good" - however I'm currently getting "#N/A".

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The concatenation is a string. value in D1 is numeric. "12345" <> 12345. That's your problem.

If you are dealing only with numeric values that are being concatenated, this will fix it by converting the concatenated string to a numeric value, which should return a match.

`=VLOOKUP((B1&C1)*1,D:E,2,False)`

If you are dealing with a mix of string and/or numeric type values in columns B&C, this might need some additional fine-tuning.

Answer (score 2):

If you concatenate two cells with `&`, Excel converts numbers to text. And internally, the text `12345` is not the same as the value `12345`.

Thus you can solve your problem with one of these options:

1. Convert the text back to a number - either using `=VLOOKUP(VALUE(B1&C1),...` or `=VLOOKUP((B1&C1)*1,...`
2. Convert column D to text (using the `TEXT` function
3. Use arithmetic instead of concatenation: `=VLOOKUP(B1*100+C1,...`

Comment: Thanks Peter for your feedback.  As always really appreciated.

Comment: You're welcome! If you found it helpful, consider upvoting! ;-) Same for David's solution!

Comment: @user1624926: I just checked your profile - 16 questions - but only 1 up vote seems not very thankful. :-(

Comment: Sorry Peter - Do not want to be considered "not very thankful". I appreciate all the input you have given me over the last couple of months.  going to look into how I "up vote" now.  I thought I could only select one answer and wasn't aware of this function.

Comment: @user1624926 See the grey triangles above and below the number next to Peter's answer? Clicking on the top one will give him and upvote. Clicking on the bottom one will result in a downvote.

Comment: Wow - didn't realize that I answered so many of your questions! Thanks for the upvotes! On a side mark: best give yourself a nickname instead - much more recognizable than the user ID...